# Simple Javascript Math

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to perform the very simple task of doing simple multiplication below. I cannot get the input field to participate in the code below. Please let me know how I might be able to get this to work. Thank you all!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$count="20";
?>
<input id="spend">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
y=<?php echo "$count"; ?>;
z=document.getElementById('spend').innerHTML;
x=y+z;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do? Echoing php in scripts is almost 99% never done.

Comment: @1337holiday I don't see any reason one should not mix PHP and jQuery. It's completely valid and useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi try this code it's working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$count=20;
?>
<input id="spend">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var y=<?php echo $count; ?>;
var z=document.getElementById('spend').value;
var x=y*z;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Brandon - Because `parseInt(y)` will not always return the number you expected. For example, `parseInt("015")` will return a number in octal (`13`). This *will* give you a big headache later on.

Comment: Derek's right; it's a standard pitfall. Use the two-argument form, `parseInt(y, 10)`.

Comment: How do you know the inputted number will be an integer? Either way, the `*` operator automatically converts the two operands to numbers before multiplying, so all you need is `var x=y*z;`. So the only difference between your code and the OP's is that they were using `+` instead, and you added the `var`s (which is a good idea). It would be *a lot more* helpful if you added any explanation instead of just claiming "it's working".

Comment: @Ravi Is there any valid reason you're not defining the `radix` parameter for your parseInt? It's like going to toilet without paper. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Thanks all, this is helpful. Some users may enter decimal places, i.e. 1.5 or 1.25, is there a simple modification that can accept non-whole numbers?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 But I don't think that's a reason to downvote. It's a simple, unfortunately not commonly known issue, that could've been more easily solved by editing the answer and adding a comment to explain, maybe with a link for reference.

Comment: @Brandon - `Number("1.25")` or just `+"1.25"`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: @Brandon I just said it - just use `var x=y*z;` - the two numbers will automatically be converted. And the only other thing to change from your code is actually using `var` to declare the variables (so they aren't global).

Comment: You guys are being picky about parseInt. On modern, es5 compliant browsers, base 10 will be assumed if the radix is not specified. @Ian on the other hand found a real problem, its not clear if the question is about addition or multiplication.

Comment: My apologies. You are all awesome!!

Comment: @Ian - But the problem is about addition while this answer is doing multiplication...

Comment: @bfavaretto Good point. But I didn't find the problem, RaviBhanvadia did by automatically changing it in the answer without an explanation. I'm just trying to point out why no explicit conversion is necessary with `*`. At the same time, this doesn't happen with `+` when one operand is a string and one is a number (which I know you know)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 That's actually unclear, the OP mentions multiplication, but his code uses addition.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 "I am trying to perform the very simple task of doing simple multiplication below." - straight from the OP. They seemed to want to multiply, but for some reason thought the `+` operator would accomplish that. The use of `*` fulfills their desire to multiply

Comment: @Brandon Just note - the `+` operator, which adds (or concatenates), needs explicit conversions when either operand isn't necessarily a number. Accessing the `.value` property of an input **always** returns a string, so you'd definitely need to use `parseFloat` (not `parseInt`) to convert before doing the addition. Again, with multiplication, the conversions are done implicitly

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I know, I know, I was too. I try to focus on what they say they want, not what they code (because that's the part not working). Either way, the OP seemed to have inadvertantly found the answer :)